# Regex: Removing Space Between Quotes, And Stopping Before a Colon (With Yahoo Pipes)

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I've been working on this for a while, but it's beyond my understanding of regex.

I'm using Yahoo Pipes on an RSS, and I want to create hashtags from titles; so, I'd like to remove space from everything between quotes, but, if there's a colon within the quotes, I only want the space removed between the words before the colon.

And, it would be great if I could also capture the unspaced words as a group, to be able to use: #$1 to output the hashtag in one step.

So, something like:

```
"The New Apple: Worlds Within Worlds" Before We Begin...
```

Could be substituted like #$1 - with this result:

```
"#TheNewApple: Worlds Within Worlds" Before We Begin...
```

After some work, I was able to come up with, this regex:

```
\s(?=\s)?|(‘|’|(Review)|:.*)
```

*("Review" was a word that often came before colons and wouldn't be stripped, if it were later in the title; that's what that's for, but I would like to not require that, to be more universal)*

But, it has two problems:

- I have to use multiple steps. The result of that regex would be:

  ```
  "TheNewApple: Worlds Within Worlds" Before We Begin...
  ```

And I could then add another regex step, to put the hash # in front

- But, it only works if the quotes are first, and I don't know how to fix that...

Comment: What language are you using? Regex is not really good at describing text *transformations*.

Comment: I'm not coding a language; I'm using **Yahoo Pipes**. I'm not good enough at coding to create an RSS filter in a language.

I think Regex is the only option...or maybe a combination of the string tools and the Regex.

I actually never read about the String modules, until now: http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=string#StringReplace

- may try those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this all in one step with regex, with a caveat. You run into problems with a repeated capturing group because only the last iteration is available in the replacement string. Searching for `( (\w+))+` and replacing with `$2` will replace **all** the words with just the last match - not what we want.

The way around this is to repeat the pattern an arbitrary number of times that will suffice for your use. Each separate group can be referenced.

Search: `"(\w+)(?: (\w+))?(?: (\w+))?(?: (\w+))?(?: (\w+))?(?: (\w+))?`

Replace: `"#$1$2$3$4$5$6`

This will replace up to 6-word titles, exactly as you need them. First, `"(\w+)` matches any word following a quote. In the replacement string, it is put back as `"#$1`, adding the hashtag. The rest is a repeated list of `(?: (\w+))?` matches, each matching a possible space and word. Notice the space is part of a non-capturing group; only the word is part of the inner capture group. In the replacement string, I have `$1$2$3$4$5$6`, which puts back the words, without the spaces. Notice that a colon will not match any part of this, so it will stop once it hits a colon.

Examples:

```
"The New Apple: Worlds Within Worlds" Before We Begin...
"The New Apple" Before We Begin...
"One: Two"
only "One" word
this has "Two Words"
"The Great Big Apple Dumpling"
"The Great Big Apple Dumpling Again: Part 2"
```

Results:

```
"#TheNewApple: Worlds Within Worlds" Before We Begin...
"#TheNewApple" Before We Begin...
"#One: Two"
only "#One" word
this has "#TwoWords"
"#TheGreatBigAppleDumpling"
"#TheGreatBigAppleDumplingAgain: Part 2"
```

Comment: Wow...

Nice!

I transferred best answer to you - tested it and it works great, but the quote was a single quote: ‘

Just a small thing :) - works perfectly.

I also really appreciate the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You can match the text with

```
"([^:]*)(.*?)"(.*)
```

then use some programming language to output the result like this:

```
'"#' + removeSpace($1) + $2 + '"' + $3
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what language you're using, but this seems like a poor choice for regex. In Python I'd do this:

```
# Python 3
import re

titles = ['''"The New Apple: Worlds Within Worlds" Before We Begin...''',
           '''"Made Up Title: For Example Only" So We Can Continue...''']

hashtagged_titles = list()
for title in titles:
    hashtagme, *restofstring = title.split(":")
    hashtag = '"#'+hashtagme[1:].translate(str.maketrans('', '', " "))
    result = "{}:{}".format(hashtag, restofstring)
    hashtagged_titles.append(result)
```

Comment: I'm using **Yahoo Pipes**, so, unfortunately, this isn't an option. Also, I haven't learned Python - but, I think Yahoo Pipes functions in a similar way?

- would be great to have an "in house" Pipes alternative, one day; so, I will make note of this answer.

Comment: I don't know anything about Yahoo Pipes and am on mobile so I can't look at it atm. I assumed it was just an API for some sort of Yahoo crawler?

Comment: Yahoo PIpes is more of an internet app. The tagline says "Like Unix pipes, simple commands can be combined together to create output that meets your needs"

So, it's, from my understanding, sort of a UI/widget combiner that lets you skip a lot of coding. Looking at the code is not an option. You just have certain pieces you can put together and a regex module is one of them.

Answer (score 1):

Do a global search for

```
\ (?=.*:)
```

Replaced with nothing. [Example](http://regex101.com/r/kP3lF8/1)

You'll need a second search on the results of that if you want to capture "TheNewApple" as a single word.

Comment: Thanks :)

I'll settle for that answer. 

If the quoted title comes later in the string, it also removes the space between the earlier words, but it handles the title first situation in a much cleaner way.